# query for dynamic operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do something like this BOLD part. I don't know if it is possible. Help me out here please.
The part between
//start and //end
Is it possible?

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, b.number, c.total,

//Start

SUM(total WHERE c.id=a.id) AS sum_total

//End

FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.id=b.id
INNER JOIN table_4 ON b.company=c.company
INNER JOIN table_3 c ON b.number=c.id_number
WHERE b.date BETWEEN 'date_1' AND 'date_2'
ORDER BY d.company ASC
```

Comment: Can you add expected result? I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want sum of entries in columns for only which have match the condition. But I actually done it right after I made this question. Thanks for quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. Try following SQL:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, b.number, SUM(c.total)TOTAL,

//Start

SUM(case when c.id=a.id then total else 0 end) AS sum_total

//End

FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.id=b.id
INNER JOIN table_4 ON b.company=c.company
INNER JOIN table_3 c ON b.number=c.id_number
WHERE b.date BETWEEN 'date_1' AND 'date_2'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY d.company ASC
```

Comment: No c.total in the select list?

Comment: It is there. SUM(c.total)TOTAL. I think he needs sum and not just total field. if he need total as field, he just need to remove sum from it and group by should be 1,2 only

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I can't understand what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I really found this helpful.

Comment: @HardikTrivediPlease accept it as answer if it deserves.

Comment: Yes @BhaveshGhodasara I accept it as an answer. It indeed deserve.

Answer (score 0):

you'd use `GROUP BY` to perform it, something like it:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, b.number, c.total,

//Start

SUM(total) AS sum_total

//End

FROM table_1 a

LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.id=b.id
INNER JOIN table_4 ON b.company=c.company
INNER JOIN table_3 c ON b.number=c.id_number
WHERE b.date BETWEEN 'date_1' AND 'date_2' AND
      c.id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.id

ORDER BY d.company ASC
```

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid (at least in newer MySQL versions.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Thanks sir. I appreciate your help.